# Handling collections in GetHashCode implementation

Tags: c#, generics, collections, gethashcode, iequatable

I'm working on implementing `GetHashCode()` based on the `HashCode` struct in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18613926). Since my `Equals` method will consider collections using `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()`, I need to include the collections in my `GetHashCode()` implementation.

As a starting point, I'm using Jon Skeet's embedded `GetHashCode()` implementation to test the output of the `HashCode` struct implementation. This works as expected using the following test below -

```
private class MyObjectEmbeddedGetHashCode
{
    public int x;
    public string y;
    public DateTimeOffset z;

    public List<string> collection;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            hash = hash * 31 + x.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 31 + y.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 31 + z.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }
}

private class MyObjectUsingHashCodeStruct
{
    public int x;
    public string y;
    public DateTimeOffset z;

    public List<string> collection;

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Start
            .Hash(x)
            .Hash(y)
            .Hash(z);
    }
}

[Test]
public void GetHashCode_CollectionExcluded()
{
    DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    MyObjectEmbeddedGetHashCode a = new MyObjectEmbeddedGetHashCode() 
    { 
        x = 1, 
        y = "Fizz",
        z = now,
        collection = new List<string>() 
        { 
            "Foo", 
            "Bar", 
            "Baz" 
        } 
    };

    MyObjectUsingHashCodeStruct b = new MyObjectUsingHashCodeStruct()
    {
        x = 1,
        y = "Fizz",
        z = now,
        collection = new List<string>() 
        { 
            "Foo", 
            "Bar", 
            "Baz" 
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine("MyObject::GetHashCode(): {0}", a.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("MyObjectEx::GetHashCode(): {0}", b.GetHashCode());

    Assert.AreEqual(a.GetHashCode(), b.GetHashCode());
}
```

The next step is to consider the collection in the `GetHashCode()` calculation. This requires a small addition to the `GetHashCode()` implementation in `MyObjectEmbeddedGetHashCode`.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 31 + x.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + y.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + z.GetHashCode();

        int collectionHash = 17;

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            collectionHash = collectionHash * 31 + item.GetHashCode();
        }

        hash = hash * 31 + collectionHash;

        return hash;
    }
}
```

However, this is a little bit more difficult in the `HashCode` struct. In this example, when a collection of type `List<string>` is passed into the `Hash<T>` method, `T` is `List<string>` so trying to cast obj to `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't work.

I can successfully cast to `IEnumerable`, but it causes boxing and I found I have to worry about excluding types like string that implement `IEnumerable`.

Is there a way to reliably cast obj to `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` in this scenario?

```
public struct HashCode
{
    private readonly int hashCode;

    public HashCode(int hashCode)
    {
        this.hashCode = hashCode;
    }

    public static HashCode Start
    {
        get { return new HashCode(17); }
    }

    public static implicit operator int(HashCode hashCode)
    {
        return hashCode.GetHashCode();
    }

    public HashCode Hash<T>(T obj)
    {
        // I am able to detect if obj implements one of the lower level
        // collection interfaces. However, I am not able to cast obj to
        // one of them since T in this case is defined as List<string>,
        // so using as to cast obj to ICollection<T> or IEnumerable<T>
        // doesn't work.
        var isGenericICollection = obj.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(
            x => x.IsGenericType && 
            x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));

        var c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        // This works but using IEnumerable causes boxing.
        // var h = c.Equals(obj, default(T)) ? 0 : ( !(obj is string) && (obj is IEnumerable) ? GetCollectionHashCode(obj as IEnumerable) : obj.GetHashCode());

        var h = c.Equals(obj, default(T)) ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode();
        unchecked { h += this.hashCode * 31; }
        return new HashCode(h);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.hashCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: `GetHashCode` is expected to be fast, reflection and iteration over all items are not the best examples of "fast" code.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?   You don't have to include the collection in the hash.   If XYZ give you a good hash distribution then stop there.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I put a stopwatch around the calling of GetHashCode with and without the LINQ query here and it runs 5 ms with it and 3 ms without, so there is a performance impact that needs to be considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can address the collection issue in a couple of ways:

1. Use a non-generic interface, e.g. `ICollection` or `IEnumerable`.
2. Add an overload for the `Hash()` method, e.g. `Hash<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) { ... }`

That said, IMHO it would be better to just leave the `struct HashCode` alone and put the collection-specific code in your actual `GetHashCode()` method. E.g.:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    HashCode hash = HashCode.Start
        .Hash(x)
        .Hash(y)
        .Hash(z);

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        hash = hash.Hash(item);
    }

    return hash;
}
```

If you do want a full-featured version of the `struct HashCode` type, it looks to me as though that same page you referenced has one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575444/3538012

The naming of the members is different, but it's basically the same idea as the `struct HashCode` type, but with overloads for other complex types (as in my suggestion #2 above). You could use that, or just apply the techniques there to your implementation of `struct HashCode`, preserving the naming conventions used in it.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because adding an overload for the Hash method provided the desired behavior. However, I encountered an infinite recursion issue which led to a StackOverflowException in my Equals() override due to a bidirectional association between a couple of my classes. This caused me to abandon including collections and my reference types in my IEquatable implementation and I ended up using a solution similar to what @Blam mentioned in a comment on my question.